# Declined flag - flagged for plagiarism, still a flag-able answer

Tags: discussion, support

[Enable and disable button in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338134/enable-and-disable-button-in-php/42339007#42339007)

I flagged for

> Plagiarism: Line for line copy of other answer to this question

I got

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

At the time I flagged it there was ALL evidence it was a cut and paste job.

The person answering it then commented that it definitely was not a copy, the comment thread was removed (possibly by same moderator) and my flag declined. The answer is STILL line for line identical to an answer one hour earlier and the low rep user who answered has not deleted the post.

I am not convinced - even the spacing smells of copy paste) it is still identical and is adding nothing to the existing answers. I do not want to risk a flag for low quality assuming I can even flag it again.

Code from [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338198/295783)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Code from [disputed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339007/295783)

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Difference: **3** (three) leading spaces before `$(document)` - in itself suspect when pasting into the editor.

Note also the lack of space before the `{` - this is NOT the disputed coder's regular use of spacing as seen in [his github code here:](https://github.com/nitinhayaran/jRange/blob/master/jquery.range.js)

---

**UPDATE:** User gave in to peer pressure and closed his own answer.

Comment: Don't have time to dig into that case, but to answer the question: Declined flags aren't overturned, and the 'review before flagging' thing is on a sliding window that will fall off with time.

Comment: Still gets on my nerves when I try to help the community..

Comment: Just so I have a clear picture: did you include a link to the other answer? Or you left it as a guessing game for the mod?

Comment: It was in the comments deleted by a mod - perhaps not the same mod? But there were only 2 other answers - the duplicate was http://stackoverflow.com/a/42338198/295783

Comment: Well, there is always a slight chance that two people come up with the same code in answers, maybe copied from somewhere else, on the same question that there would be barely enough evidence to have a clear case of plagiarism. For such claims to hold you need to find an authentic source outside of the current Q/A pair. Better just vote on the content and move on.

Comment: @rene sure - but the END result is the same - a useless addition and only my willingness to help keeping SO clean is affected now

Comment: sure, I would have left long ago when I cared about that not all my close votes lead to actual closure of a question. Just vote and flag as you see fit and stop wasting your and my energy when your moderation now and then doesn't work out as intended. Shrug it off.

Answer (score 5):

The posts are **not** line for line identical. Kishan's code doesn't disable the `<button type="submit" id="submit" ...>` button for example, and there are spacing differences in the JS code. The JS code is not rocket science, it is not unheard of for multiple people to end up writing what is basically the same code.

I also looked at other contributions by the user up to that point, and didn't find any clear smoking guns they are in the habit of copying other answers.

As such, I didn't see enough evidence that the post was plagiarised and declined the flag.

Comment: The code posted had 3 leading spaces before the first statement as the only difference - which answer are you comparing ?

Comment: @mplungjan: [Enable and disable button in PHP](//stackoverflow.com/a/42338198). Again, the JS is *trivial enough*.

Comment: See the code in my updated question here

Comment: @mplungjan: yes, they are similar. But there are differences elsewhere. You asked for why I declined, I gave my reasons. Did you want to change the question to "but it is plagiarism anyway" now?

Comment: @mplungjan: this isn't a clear straight copy&paste-the-whole-post job, so judging what is and what isn't plagiarism is a subjective call. My call is that it wasn't.

Comment: Sigh. The code was identical apart from 3 spaces which were in themselves suspect. Not adding ANYTHING new - one full hour after. I stand by any flag needed to delete the answer. Too bad you disagree

Comment: Sorry to flog this horse, BUT The **ONLY** difference is the 3 leading spaces. He commented that he always copy from his own editor - but then he has suddenly decided to NOT have spaces between the ) and { in `function(e){` as he has in his [github code](https://github.com/nitinhayaran/jRange/blob/master/jquery.range.js) - I am more and more convinced it is a copypaste from the first example in [the link I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42338198/295783)